# Permalink rewriterule with same filename as rule

Tags: php, macos, apache, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm using Mac OSX Lion and native apache, php5 install the rewrite engine is working still there is a problem and this problem is better shown than explained so I have these 2 rules below and one works and the other does not:

```
RewriteRule ^imovel/([a-z_A-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-z_A-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-z_A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /imovel.php?imovel=$1
```

This rule dosent work it goes to the file imovel.php, but it dont pass the variable, so if I change this ^imovel/ to anything else like ^blerg/ works nicely like below

```
RewriteRule ^blerg/([a-z_A-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-z_A-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-z_A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /imovel.php?imovel=$1
```

This rule works fine, but this problem only shows on the mac I work with. With these same rules on Windows 7 work's fine. Is there any configuration I need to do in apache to change this?

Comment: can you give an example of a URL that you are going to that this should work with?

Comment: blabla.local/imovel/47/apartment/executive_lunai/ -> this dint work

Comment: blabla.local/blerg/47/apartment/executive_lunai/ -> this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You site must have `MultiViews` enables. If so, `/imovel.php` would load by typing in `/imovel` and therefore, it is loading `/imovel.php` and not your rewrite code. But removing `MultiViews` you will eliminate this problem.

In order to fix this I had to add a few lines of code to my `httpd.conf`, `vhost.conf` or my `user.conf` file under `<Directory "/Users/User/Sites">` file using the terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
sudo nano /etc/apache2/users/user.conf
sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have no idea where to find these files in lion, but in mac osx maverick, it was in `/etc/apache2/`, but it is and will be in the Apache2 folder, and in this file, which ever file above has your sites directory, the code I had to remove `MultiViews` from the `options`. `/Users/User/Sites` is my own folder so ignore that and look for your own site folder.

```
<Directory "/Users/User/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

so it now looks like this

```
<Directory "/Users/User/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Once I did so, /index.php page can no longer be loaded by typing /index. And therefore, I could use the code I originally used in my .htaccess file. And all is solved in paradise.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/57243/apache-mod-rewrite-fails-when-file-by-same-name-exists):

> Do you have
>   [`mod_negotiation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html)
>   installed?  If so, that'll take your request for new and try to work
>   out what file you really meant to send.  Make sure you don't have
>   `Options MultiViews` set. So, in the `.htaccess` put `Options
>   -MultiViews`.